# npm installs each package twice

Tags: npm, homebrew

I have just installed Homebrew and then I have installed Node (via `$ brew install node`). When node was installed, `npm` was automatically installed too (why?).

anyway, now when I install any package from `npm`, for example `$ npm install -g express` - it is installed in two locations:

`Users/myuser/.npm/express` and `usr/local/lib/node_modules/express`

`$ which express` retrieves me `usr/local/bin/express` which refers to `usr/local/lib/node_modules/express`. I think it's ok that it's installed inside `usr/local/lib/node_modules/..` because I used `-g` flag; but why it is also installed under my own user (`Users/myuser/.npm`)?

In addition, how does the terminal know about `express` command? I didn't define any `.bash_profile` file. how does it know to go to `usr/local/bin/$PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node installs NPM also because **Node without NPM wouldn't be Node!** :)
NPM is all about a succesful registry. You wouldn't go much further without it.

`~/.npm` is a cache for all packages - so this actually isn't an installation. As you may know about caches, this is just to avoid re-downloading things over time.
Also, this is configurable via the [`cache` config](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html#cache).

Finally, the last location - `usr/local/lib/node_modules` is the actual global installation of Express.